# Import excel file to sql server in asp.net with check existing record in table before import

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, import

Sorry my Enghist is not good!

How to check excel fie, if a row existing in table do'nt import this row

My function work well for import (not check existing)

```
string excelConnectionString = "";
    string strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
    string strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.FileName).ToString().ToLower();
    fileuploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType));
    string strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType);
    //Connection String to Excel Workbook
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
    }

  //Create Connection to Excel work book
    OleDbConnection excelConnection =new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
    //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [account_id], [type],[first_name], [last_name], [title], [birthday], [tel],[phone], [email_1],[email_2], [remark],[del_if] from [Sheet1$]",excelConnection);
    excelConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
    //Give your Destination table name
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "contact";

    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to be possible using SqlBulkCopy. What you could do, is write the data to a staging table, and only copy across the records that don't already exist. Then you can clear out the staging table once your copy is complete.

**Edit:**

Given your comment about not wanting to use a staging table, you could possibly find a distinct list of key values (possibly account_id from your example) from your "contact" table before reading data from the excel file, and then use the list to exclude records you read from the excel file. The benefits to this are you aren't reading data from the excel file that you don't need to. The downside is that this might not be all that efficient if your "contact" table is huge or if the key you'd use to compare the data isn't something simple like account_id.

Another alternative could be, if you're excel file isn't huge, to insert records row by row using a where clause on the insert to ensure the insert won't create unnecessary duplicates. This will be significantly slower than SqlBulkCopy, but it'll work.

Comment: If can't use SqlBulkCopy, i can use another way. I only want resolve "check before import". Write to staging table, then copy records that don't already exist to other talbe may be more complex

Comment: @Hainlp- There are a couple of alternatives listed in my edited post. I hope they are of some use. Good luck. The main issue is SqlBulkCopy isn't useful for selective inserts. It simply stuffs data in as quick as possible. The crux of the issue is to either filter the data you need to stuff into the database first, or don't use SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: @ Mr Moose: thanks you. I think i need to read more about store procedure and find other way to import(don't use SqlBulkCopy). Thanks Mr Moose again :).